# How to do transfer learning on a pre-trained ResNet50 with different image size

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have a pretrained ResNet model which is trained on 64x64 images. I would like to do transfer learning with new dataset that contains 200x200 images.

I am loading the model like:

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(64,64,3))
model.load_weights("a trained model weights on 64x64")

model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False

x = model.output
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(101, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

top_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)

top_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=adam,
        metrics=[accuracy])

EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 4424 // BATCH_SIZE
VALIDATION_STEPS = 466 // BATCH_SIZE

callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(schedule=Schedule(EPOCHS, initial_lr=lr_rate)),
                ModelCheckpoint(str(output_dir) + "/weights.{epoch:03d}-{val_loss:.3f}-{val_age_mae:.3f}.hdf5",
                                 monitor="val_age_mae",
                                 verbose=1,
                                 save_best_only=False,
                                 mode="min")
                 ]

hist = top_model.fit_generator(generator=train_set,
                               epochs=EPOCHS,
                               steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                               validation_data=val_set,
                               validation_steps = VALIDATION_STEPS,
                               verbose=1,
                               callbacks=callbacks)
```

I would like to do transfer learning based with images of 200x200 pixels. I am very new to this, how can I modify?

is there a way to modify the model input shape? and do I. need to do something with spatial size?

And which optimizer is recommended? Adam or SGD?

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 512)    1049088     activation_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 512)    2048        res5c_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_47 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 512)    2359808     activation_47[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 512)    2048        res5c_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_48 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 2048)   1050624     activation_48[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 2048)   8192        res5c_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_16 (Add)                    (None, 2, 2, 2048)   0           bn5c_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_49 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 2048)   0           add_16[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pred_age (Dense)                (None, 2, 2, 101)    206848      activation_49[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,794,560
Trainable params: 23,741,440
Non-trainable params: 53,120
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Getting the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is your approach working?

Comment: My approach is not working:( As I am new to this, Is it possible to do transfer learning on different image size on a pretrained model with different image size?

Comment: What error message states?

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)

Comment: Please update your question with your full code. Specifically, add output of `top_model.summary()`, and if you try to use `.fit(), add shape of input data. Also add error messages. That'll make your question clear and specific

Comment: Updated the questions, Hope the question is clear. I want to change the input shape of the current model(trained on 64x64 images) with transfer learning on new data of (200x200)

Answer (score 0):

Consider example, I used your model as is, changed only input data.

```
test = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128, 3)
```

As you may see, it's a random array, 10 batches of size `128, 128, 3`

```
top_model.fit(test, epochs=1, batch_size=1, steps_per_epoch = 10)
```

Then I used fit method, just to demonstrate.

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape
>   (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)

This is the error message. It's obvious that your input data is of wrong shape. Add function, that produces `generator=train_set`. And it's better to use Dataset API with fit method. It's easier and faster. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets